# Ordering tdm in specific order, not frequencies

Tags: r, text-mining

I have this corpus of documents, properly pre-processed. Working with R package tm, i do: `adtm <-DocumentTermMatrix(a) 
adtm <- removeSparseTerms(adtm, 0.75)
findFreqTerms(adtm, lowfreq=10) # find terms with a frequency higher than 10`
 I then build an adjacency matrix and do some network plots in igraph. How can I group the columns on identified entities? Let say, I want the first five columns of the DocumentTermMatrix to be the five cities of interest to me. Other cities follow from 6:n. Basically how do I re-order adtm other than by frequency? in above snippet, findFreqTerms(xx,xx=10) may not even show up Cordoba because it appears in less than ten documents. But what i want to study is column Cardoba and its adjacency + network graphs to other cities in Spain.
Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Not sure CV is the most appropriate venue for this kind of question....

Comment: @lukeA has an elegant solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346014/how-to-select-named-columns-from-a-documenttermmatrix-in-r-using-tm). But I still get an error with the intersect operation: `Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'`.